# How to create scrollable tabs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In the web world I have scrollable tabs offered by material-ui that looks like that.
[image]

I am trying create the same thing using flutter, I did a listview in a row however I am unable to create the `next` and `previous` buttons.

Help or a reference of the  widget if it is already made is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is `preview` button?

Comment: `previous` sorry, check the edit @Mobina

Comment: Are you sure that you need the arrow buttons? It will be a bit complex to achieve. There's a "TabBar" widget that has "isScrollable" parameter. [https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/tabbed-app-bar](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/tabbed-app-bar)

Comment: the arrow buttons are the main issues I am facing, so yeah @Thepeanut

Answer (score 4):

Check this out

```
Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  onPressed: (){
                    if(_tabController.index > 0){
                      _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index - 1);
                    }else{
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Can't go back"),));
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBar(
                    isScrollable: true,
                    controller: _tabController,
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black
                    ),
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                    labelColor: Colors.blue,
                    tabs: List.generate(
                      20,
                      (index) {
                        return Tab(
                          text: "Tab $index",
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                  onPressed: (){
                    if(_tabController.index+1 < 20){
                      _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index + 1);
                    }else{
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Can't move forward"),));
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        )
```

[image]

Comment: +1, I wanted the buttons to jump to the next viewport of the list However thanks you, you put me on the right track